# Grid not docking

Tags: wpf

1. The grid at the bottom, that contains buttons won't dock. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I make this same grid not share the column that the entire window defines? e.i I 
   want to the grid that won't dock to have it's own column, and it will contain 3 buttons

   ```
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <Label Content="Temp" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" />
       <Label Content="Date" Grid.Row="1"/>
       <DatePicker Grid.Row="2" />
       <Label Content="Note" Grid.Row="3" />
       <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Background="WhiteSmoke"/>
       <Separator Width="auto" Grid.Row="5" Margin="0 10 0 10" Background="Black"/>
       <TextBox Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="WhiteSmoke" MinHeight="150" IsReadOnly="True" />
       <Label Content="Done" Grid.Row="7" />
       <CheckBox Name="doneCheck" Grid.Row="7" Margin="40 7 0 0" />

       <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
           <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
               <Button Content="Add" Name="SubmitButton" />
               <Button Content="Get Records" Name="GetRecsButton" />
           </Grid>
       </DockPanel>
   </Grid>
   ```

Comment: I cannot see any DockPanel object.

Comment: You may need to read up on panels, from the beginning. Docking only works inside a DockPanel and arguments such as Auto are case sensitive.

Comment: I did try with the dockpanel at first, which didn't work either. I just forgot to put it back when posting, cus of c&p.
I have edited the code, where it shows my first attempt

Comment: This correctly puts the inner Grid at the bottom of the DockPanel. In the code you specify that you want the DockPanel to be drawn in row 0 (default value if Grid.Row not specified), which is at the top of the outer Grid.

Comment: Even if I give it Grid.Row="8" (Or whatever last index), it still wont dock. It will be at the bottom, but not dock, so when resizing the window, the grid doesn't follow

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the `DockPanel` at the top of the outer `Grid`. You have to place it at the bottom:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Temp" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" />
    <Label Content="Date" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <DatePicker Grid.Row="2" />
    <Label Content="Note" Grid.Row="3" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Background="WhiteSmoke"/>
    <Separator Width="auto" Grid.Row="5" Margin="0 10 0 10" Background="Black"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="WhiteSmoke" MinHeight="150" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <Label Content="Done" Grid.Row="7" />
    <CheckBox Name="doneCheck" Grid.Row="7" Margin="40 7 0 0" />

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Button Content="Add" Name="SubmitButton" />
            <Button Content="Get Records" Name="GetRecsButton" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Of course that means there is no point in having the `DockPanel` in the first place. You could however do everything with a `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel  LastChildFill="True">
    <Label Content="Temp" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="18" />
    <Label Content="Date" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <DatePicker DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <Label Content="Note" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="WhiteSmoke"/>
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="WhiteSmoke" MinHeight="150" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <Label Content="Done" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <CheckBox Name="doneCheck" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="40 7 0 0" />

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
        <Button Content="Add" Name="SubmitButton" />
        <Button Content="Get Records" Name="GetRecsButton" />
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```